# Pandas, Matplotlib and stacked bar chart with 3 values

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following code representing 3 values I would like to display in a stacked bar chart.

```
print(df.groupby(['project']).sum()['no_test_or_requirement'])
print(df.groupby(['project']).sum()['requirement_only'])
print(df.groupby(['project']).sum()['test_and_requirement'])

width = .5
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(13,9))
plt.ylabel('Count')
plt.xlabel('Project')
ax.yaxis.grid(linewidth=.5)
p1 = ax.bar(df['project'].unique(), df.groupby(['project']).sum()['no_test_or_requirement'], color='y', width=.5)
p2 = ax.bar(df['project'].unique(), df.groupby(['project']).sum()['requirement_only'], color='b', width=.5)
p3 = ax.bar(df['project'].unique(), df.groupby(['project']).sum()['test_and_requirement'], color='r', width=.5)
fig.legend((p1[0], p2[0], p3[0]), ('No Test or Requirement', 'Requirement Only', 'Test and Requirement'))
plt.show()
```

The following is the output from the print statements that reflect the three values in question.

```
project
ENTMQ      3
ENTMQBR    0
RHDM       1
RHPAM      1
Name: no_test_or_requirement, dtype: int64
project
ENTMQ      13
ENTMQBR     3
RHDM        0
RHPAM       0
Name: requirement_only, dtype: int64
project
ENTMQ      5
ENTMQBR    1
RHDM       0
RHPAM      0
Name: test_and_requirement, dtype: int64
```

My resulting chart will only show two values stacked and only shows "No Test or Requirement" values when the other values aren't present. The values presented are correct; however, I do expect to see "No Test or Requirement" represented in the ENTMQ and ENTMQBR bars (3 stacked values).  What am I missing here?

[image: chart]

Comment: I think above all you are missing a [mcve] such that people would actually be able to run your code and see at which point is goes wrong.

Comment: looks like your df is pretty small, you could just print it out at the bottom of your question and then people could work on modifying your code and see the results

Comment: This is not a stacked bar chart at all but just the yellow bars in the back, the blue bars in the middle and the red bars in front. If that's all you want, just change the plotting sequence to have yellow in front. If you want the bars stacked on top of each other, it's probably best to plot a DataFrame object all at once: https://pstblog.com/2016/10/04/stacked-charts

Comment: So this works
df2.plot(kind='bar',stacked=True, figsize=(13,9))

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me.

```
df2 = df.groupby(['project']).sum()

df2 = df2.drop(columns=['has_requirement', 'has_testcase'])
ax = df2.plot(kind='barh',stacked=True, figsize=(13,9),
        color=('r','g','b', 'y'))

ax.set_xlabel('Count')
ax.set_ylabel('Project')
ax.xaxis.grid(linewidth=1)
plt.show()
```